# Django: TypeError while using Atomic Operations

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-models

I have a django app in google app engine.
In a particular model I have `IntegerField` default to `0` and want to atomic increment it.

I have done like this on user form submission

```
from django.db.models import F

pobj.right_answers = F('right_answers') + 1
pobj.save()
```

When I do this, the program is raising the below

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ExpressionNode'
```

Why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: There is no such thing as an atomic increment on a datastore property in appengine.  You need to use transactions if your concerned about concurrent updates.  What is `F` , my guess it some hi-level entity that `F('right_answers') + 1` is returning an `ExpressionNode`.

Comment: This is the docs for `F` method https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#django.db.models.F